# .link() function Javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

How can I display my data in the new tab which opens using **.link()** in Javascript?

For eg. I have a JSON data, a part of which has to be displayed in the new tab redirected by my `link()` function. This is what I am doing:

```
var result=str.link("data:text/html," +mydata ,"_blank", "width=200,height=100");
```

This is appending mydata to the url but not to the body.

Comment: `link` function only takes `url` as argument [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link)

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation on MDN for the [link method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link):

> **Deprecated**
>   This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code

So don't use it. Use `createElement` instead.

```
var result = document.createElement("a");
result.href = "data:text/html," + mydata;
result.target = "_blank";
result.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
```

(If you did want to continue using the link method, the solution is still the same: Set the target property as a separate statement. The link method doesn't have any options to set it itself).